# Unable to view to the clustering results in rviz

Tags: ros, kinect, pcl, 3d-object-recognition, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am trying to perform euclidean clustering in ROS. I can generate data and also store them .pcd files. But i wish to see the output of the file in rviz which  I am unable to. It throws the following warning:

```
[WARN] [1426601373.806774699]: Invalid argument passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot be empty
```

My code looks like this:

```
ros::Publisher pub;

void cloud_cb(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& input){

sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::Ptr clusters (new sensor_msgs::PointCloud2);  
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>), cloud_f (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
pcl::fromROSMsg(*input, *cloud);
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr clustered_cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);   
    
std::cout << "PointCloud before filtering has: " << cloud->points.size () << " data points." << std::endl;

// Create the filtering object: downsample the dataset using a leaf size of 1cm
pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PointXYZ> vg;
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_filtered (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
vg.setInputCloud (cloud);
vg.setLeafSize (0.01f, 0.01f, 0.01f);
vg.filter (*cloud_filtered);
std::cout << "PointCloud after filtering has: " << cloud_filtered->points.size ()  << " data points." << std::endl;

// Create the segmentation object for the planar model and set all the parameters
pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PointXYZ> seg;
pcl::PointIndices::Ptr inliers (new pcl::PointIndices);
pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients (new pcl::ModelCoefficients);
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_plane (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> ());
pcl::PCDWriter writer;
seg.setOptimizeCoefficients (true);
seg.setModelType (pcl::SACMODEL_PLANE);
seg.setMethodType (pcl::SAC_RANSAC);
seg.setMaxIterations (100);
seg.setDistanceThreshold (0.02);

int i=0, nr_points = (int) cloud_filtered->points.size ();
while (cloud_filtered->points.size () > 0.3 * nr_points)
{
    // Segment the largest planar component from the remaining cloud
    seg.setInputCloud (cloud_filtered);
        seg.segment (*inliers, *coefficients);
        if (inliers->indices.size () == 0)
     {
            std::cout << "Could not estimate a planar model for the given dataset." << std::endl;
            break;
         }

    // Extract the planar inliers from the input cloud
pcl::ExtractIndices<pcl::PointXYZ> extract;
    extract.setInputCloud (cloud_filtered);
    extract.setIndices (inliers);
    extract.setNegative (false);

    // Get the points associated with the planar surface
    extract.filter (*cloud_plane);
    std::cout << "PointCloud representing the planar component: " << cloud_plane->points.size () << " data points." << std::endl;

    // Remove the planar inliers, extract the rest
    extract.setNegative (true);
    extract.filter (*cloud_f);
    *cloud_filtered = *cloud_f;
}

// Creating the KdTree object for the search method of the extraction
 pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tree (new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>);
tree->setInputCloud (cloud_filtered);

std::vector<pcl::PointIndices> cluster_indices;
pcl::EuclideanClusterExtraction<pcl::PointXYZ> ec;
ec.setClusterTolerance (0.02); // 2cm
ec.setMinClusterSize (10);
ec.setMaxClusterSize (2500);
ec.setSearchMethod (tree);
ec.setInputCloud (cloud_filtered);
ec.extract (cluster_indices);
std::vector<pcl::PointIndices>::const_iterator it;
std::vector<int>::const_iterator pit;

 int j = 0; 
for(it = cluster_indices.begin(); it != cluster_indices.end(); ++it) {
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_cluster (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
        for(pit = it->indices.begin(); pit != it->indices.end(); pit++) {
        //push_back: add a point to the end of the existing vector
                cloud_cluster->points.push_back(cloud_filtered->points[*pit]); 
        
        cloud_cluster->width = cloud_cluster->points.size ();
            cloud_cluster->height = 1;
            cloud_cluster->is_dense = true;


        std::stringstream ss;
            ss << "cloud_cluster_" << j << ".pcd";
            writer.write<pcl::PointXYZ> (ss.str (), *cloud_cluster, false); //*
            j++;
        }

        //Merge current clusters to whole point cloud
        *clustered_cloud += *cloud_cluster;

 }

pcl::toROSMsg (*clustered_cloud , *clusters);
pub.publish (*clusters);}

 int main (int argc, char** argv)
  {
// Initialize ROS
ros::init (argc, argv, "clust");
ros::NodeHandle nh;

    // Create a ROS subscriber for the input point cloud
ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe ("input", 1, cloud_cb);



// Create a ROS publisher for the output model coefficients
    //pub = nh.advertise<pcl_msgs::ModelCoefficients> ("output", 1);
    pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> ("clusters", 1);
    // Spin
    ros::spin ();
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225245/unable-to-view-to-the-clustering-results-in-rviz./) by [blackmamba591](https://answers.ros.org/users/23981/blackmamba591/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2016-01-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-01-27**:
I haven't looked at this too closely, but I'd try making sure the `header` field of the `clusters` cloud  matches the `header` field of the `input` cloud. Is the conversion to PCL and back to PointCloud2 properly preserving the frame information?

**Comment by [blackmamba591](https://answers.ros.org/users/23981/blackmamba591/) on 2016-01-27**:
Thanks jarvis, I have done so. Its solved.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-01-27**:
I just came back here to tell you that I was convinced that was the problem... glad to hear that it was an easy fix!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`frame_id` of the `header`of the pointcloud-message needs to be set.

```
clusters->header.frame_id = "/camera_depth_frame";
clusters->header.stamp=ros::Time::now();
pub.publish (*clusters);
```

This will solve the problem.

---

Originally posted by [blackmamba591](https://answers.ros.org/users/23981/blackmamba591/) with karma: 38 on 2016-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0